# How to perform user authentication using Google credentials via a FLASK REST API / Vue SPA stack

Tags: python, vue.js, authentication, flask, oauth-2.0

I have a little experience prototyping Flask REST APIs / VueJs SPAs and have followed tutorials before which implement user authentication within a standard Flask app using the flask sessions library.

For my current project though, I would like to implement user authentication using people's **Google** user credentials (and OAuth2?) on top of an existing Flask REST API. The REST API serves a pre-compiled client VueJS app via the base route "/", and all other endpoints are available to users via autogenerated Swagger docs, which the client app engages with from time to time. I want these other routes to be protected though and I'm not sure how to do this.

I followed a great tutorial https://realpython.com/flask-google-login/ which implements a basic (and easily understandable) OAuth2 client/provider handshake and user authentication flow. I'm not sure how to modify the code to work with my REST API.

One thing I have tried (unsuccessfully) is to create a dedicated endpoint which generates a popup window with the standard Google sign in box, and then try to capture the resulting tokens and add them to the headers of all future requests made to the REST API (...or something along those lines). I tried to use [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/) for this, but ran into this error because the window needs to be started from within the main Flask thread (I'm not sure how to achieve that):
`Error: webview.util.WebViewException: This function must be run from a main thread. in multithreading python`

I think I lack some fundamentals on OAuth2/JWT/whatever else I should be considering, **so I'm really looking for some more theoretical suggestions here as to a logical/common flow to follow**.
Note: must use google service as the auth provider.
Any assistance would be much appreciated!